# Cookie is not sent in XHR request / cross-domain

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, cookies, kotlin, cross-domain

#### Step 1

Client makes an HTTP request to `GET https://sub.d0main.com/getWithCookie`

#### Step 2

The request is proxied by nginx and routed to Spring Boot application, where it's handled:

```
GetMapping("/getWithCookie")
fun getWithCookie(response: HttpServletResponse) {
  val cookie = Cookie("longCookie", "42")
  cookie.maxAge = 500
  response.addCookie(cookie)
  response.sendRedirect("https://d0main.com/renderPage")
}
```

#### Step 3

The "/renderPage" endpoint produces an HTML+JS page which contains a submit button with the following handler:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://sub.d0main.com/postWithCookie', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({}));
```

#### Step 4

Browser renders this page and user clicks the submit button. Note, the page address is `https://d0main.com/renderPage` and there's a cookie with domain `sub.d0main.com`.

#### Step 5

The request is proxied by nginx and routed to Spring Boot application, where it should be handled.
The `/postWithCookie` mapping looks like

```
@PostMapping("/postWithCookie", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun postWithCookie(
@CookieValue("longCookie") longCookie: Long) {
  // ...
}
```

But Spring Boot rejects the request with status code 400, because the required cookie parameter is missing. The actual response looks like:

```
{
  "timestamp":"2019-08-26T07:48:29.930+0000",
  "status":400,
  "error":"Bad Request",
  "message":"Missing cookie 'longCookie' for method parameter of type long",
  "path":"/postWithCookie"
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: cookies should be sent after the preflight request that match the same parent domain.

Comment: @夢のの夢 what does it mean?

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue, I think, but THINK it was working until recently but stopped working.  So it is important also to mention things like client version, like Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)